# Remove All tags Manager after submitting the form

Tags: javascript, tags

I am using the tags manager library which is working perfectly, but the problem is that I don't know how to refresh and remove all the tags after submitting the ajax form.
Can anyone help me to know about it please?

```
<html>

<head>

     <title>tags example</title>

     <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap-tagmanager.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/css/bootstrap-tagmanager.css"></script>

     <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 </head>

 <body>

 <input type="text" name="tags" placeholder="Tags" class="tagsManager"/>


<script type="text/javascript">     
$('.tagsManager).tagsmanger();  
</script>

 

 </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: You are missing a `'` in `$('.tagsManager)`

Comment: Also you might need to add jquery referece before the tag manager library

Comment: It just a typing error while asking question, but in actual code everything is fine, I just want to know that how can I remove all the tags from hidden input as well as from span tags after successfully submitting the form

Comment: On ajax success `$('input').tagsinput('removeAll');` ??